Textual criticism applied to Hindu texts?
Are there any scholary papers which apply methods of higher textual criticism to Hindu texts, e.g. to the Bhagavata Purana or the Bhagavad Gita? If yes, I am interested in some references.
I ask this question because in other fields of Religious Studies or theology, e.g., within the study of protestantic theology the methods of textual criticism have been applied to biblical texts since more than 100 years, under the title "Historisch-kritische Bibelwissenschaft".

I think there is in brief and maybe not in detail, but the problem is they are highly biased leftist people. So you get only one sided narration if that's what you like.

There are no such organized studies in Indian universities. The reason is that there is a law introduced in the early 20th century that forbids criticism of any religious text. The law was introduced by the British after a Hindu writer was beheaded by a Muslim for writing a book on the Prophet. There was some talk about 10 years ago about introducing such studies. However while BJP leaders agreed the secularists objected since such a study might criticize scriptures of certain religion that will precipitate riots.

There are, but they are in sanskrit between sanskrit scholars. In his seminal 5 volume work A History of Indian Philosophy by Surendranath Dasgupta (Motilal Banarsidass Publishers [India - mlbd.com, in the west it may be available on Amazon for hardcopy books] and here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism he writes in his Chapter 1, Introductory (vol. 1) -

Indian modes of expression, entailing difficult technical philosophical terms are so different from those of European thought, that they can hardly ever be accurately translated. It is therefore very difficult for a person unacquainted with Sanskrit to understand Indian philosophical thought in its true bearing from translations. Pāli is a much easier language than Sanskrit, but a knowledge of Pāli is helpful in understanding only the earliest school of Buddhism, when it was in its semi-philosophical stage. Sanskrit is generally regarded as a difficult language. But no one from an acquaintance with Vedic or ordinary literary Sanskrit can have any idea of the difficulty of the logical and abstruse parts of Sanskrit philosophical literature. A man who can easily understand the Vedas, the Upaniṣads, the Purāṇas, the Law Books and the literary works, and is also well acquainted with European philosophical thought, may find it literally impossible to understand even small portions of a work of advanced Indian logic, or the dialectical Vedānta. This is due to two reasons, the use of technical terms and of great condensation in expression, and the hidden allusions to doctrines of other systems.
The tendency to conceiving philosophical problems in a clear and unambiguous manner is an important feature of Sanskrit thought,but from the ninth century onwards, the habit of using clear, definite, and precise expressions,began to develop inaverystriking manner, and as a result of that a large number of technical terms began tobe invented. These terms are seldom properly explained, and it is presupposed that the reader who wants to read the works should have a knowledge of them. Any one in olden times who took to the study of any system of philosophy, had to do so with a teacher, who explained those terms to him. The teacher himself had got it from his teacher, and he from his. There was no tendency to popularize philosophy, for the idea then prevalent was that only the chosen few who had otherwise shown their fitness, deserved to become fit students (adhikārl) of philosophy, under the direction of a teacher. Only those who had the grit and high moral strength to devote their whole life to the true understanding of philosophy and the rebuilding of life in accordance with the high truths of philosophy were allowed to study it.
Another difficulty which a beginner will meet is this, that sometimes the same technical terms are used in extremely different senses in different systems. The student must know the meaning of each technical term with reference to the system in which it occurs, and no dictionary will enlighten him much about the matter[1]. He will have to pick them up as he advances and finds them used. Allusions to the doctrines of other systems and their refutations during the discussions of similar doctrines in any particular system of thought are often very puzzling even to a well-equipped reader; for he cannot be expected to know all the doctrines of other systems without going through them, and so it often becomes difficult to follow the series of answers and refutations which are poured forth in the course of these discussions. There are two important compendiums in Sanskrit giving a summary of some of the principal systems of Indian thought, viz. the Sarvadarśanasaṃgraha , and the Ṣaḍdarśanasamuccaya of Haribhadra with the commentary of Guṇaratna; but the former is very sketchy and can throw very little light on the understanding of the ontological or epistemological doctrines of any of the systems. It has been translated by Cowell and Gough, but I am afraid the translation may not be found very intelligible.
Guṇaratna’s commentary is excellent so far as Jainism is concerned, and it sometimes gives interesting information about other systems, and also supplies us with some short bibliographical notices, but it seldom goes on to explain the epistemological or ontological doctrines or discussions which are so necessary for the right understanding of any of the advanced systems of Indian thought. Thus in the absence of a book which could give us in brief the main epistemological, ontological, and psychological positions of the Indian thinkers, it is difficult even for a good Sanskrit scholar to follow the advanced philosophical literature, even though he may be acquainted with many of the technical philosophical terms. I have spoken enough about the difficulties of studying Indian philosophy, but if once a person can get himself used to the technical terms and the general positions of the different Indian thinkers and their modes of expression, he can master the whole by patient toil.
The technical terms, which are a source of difficulty at the beginning, are of inestimable value in helping us to understand the precise and definite meaning of the writers who used them, and the chances of misinterpreting or misunderstanding them are reduced to a minimum. It is I think well-known that avoidance of technical terms has often rendered philosophical works unduly verbose, and liable to misinterpretation. The art of clear writing is indeed a rare virtue and every philosopher cannot expect to have it. But when technical expressions are properly formed, even a bad writer can make himself understood. In the early days of Buddhist philosophy in the Pāli literature, this difficulty is greatly felt. There are some technical terms here which are still very elastic and their repetition in different places in more or less different senses heighten the difficulty of understanding the real meaning intended to be conveyed.

and Swami Vivekananda writes in his Complete Works:

Comin to our commentators again, we find another difficulty. The Advaitic commentator, whenever an Advaitic text comes, preserves it just as it is; but the same commentator, as soon as a dualistic text presents itself, tortures it if he can, and brings the most queer meaning out of it. Sometimes the "Unborn" becomes a "goat", such is the wonderful changes effected. To suit the commentator, "Aja [diacritical mark over the second 'a'] the Unborn is explained as Aja [no diacritical mark] a she-goat. In the same way, if not in a still worse fashion, the texts are handled by the dualistic commentator. Every dualistic text is preserved, and every text that speaks of non-dualistic philosophy is tortured in any fashion he likes. This Sanskrit language is so intricate, the Sanskrit of the Vedas so ancient, and the Sanskrit philology so perfect, that any amount of discussion can be carried on for ages in regard to the meaning of one word. If a Pandit takes it into his head, he can render anybody's prattle into correct Sanskrit by force of argument and quotation of text and rules. These are the difficulties in our way of understanding the Upanishads.

As an example, Sanskrit has no sentences, it has 'stops'. In reading or interpreting a text, a commentator can change the stop rendering a different meaning to the text.
Another scholarly reference is here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey and goes in and out of print at the same Indian publisher as Prof. DasGupta's books. It was written in the early 60s as the author's PhD thesis.

you asked about the Gita. You might like to read Gambhirananda's Introduction to his translation of the Gita here - https://archive.org/details/bhagavad-gita-with-the-commentary-of-adi-shankaracharya-by-swami-gambhirananda-a/page/n1/mode/2up?view=theater There is also avery good out of print book that specifically talks about the difficulty in translation/interpretation of texts. "Philosophy East/Philosophy West; A critical Comparison of Indian, Chinese, Islamic, and European Philosophy" by Ben-Ami Scharfstein, Ilai Alon, Shlomo Biderman...Oxford University Press 1978.
